# I want NOT to escape HTML tag in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am newbie of AngularJS. I want *NOT* to escape HTML tag, so

1. include **angular-sanitize.js**
2. write the code below:

```
<!-- <div>{{article.content}}</div> -->
<div ng-bind-html="{{article.content}}"></div>
```

But nothing is being rendered.

Comment: Have you included sanitize like this: `angular.module("myapp", ["ngSanitize"])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be help you.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YzTopQejIJbjZBtk5EJz?p=preview)

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', ctrl]);

function ctrl($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.getContent = function() {
    return "shohel rana";
  };
}
```

```
<body ng-controller="appCtrl">
  <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <div ng-bind-html="getContent()"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the braces:

```
<div ng-bind-html="article.content"></div>
```

you also need to make sure angular knows that it's safe in your controller:

```
$sce.trustAsHtml($scope.article.content);
```

Comment: Are you sure `$sce` is needed if you don't link sources outside the application? The other answer's [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YzTopQejIJbjZBtk5EJz?p=preview) seems to work fine without.

Comment: True, I'm not sure how - in all the angular docs it says you have to sanitise the output and I've had experience with things that don't work unless you mark them to be trusted. It's possible that it's dependent on what the source is - I was pulling info back from a web service, maybe angular trusts local strings and functions implicitly. That's just my supposition though, not fact.